# Parsed date in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use parsed date in `where` clause with 2 tables f.e

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
INNER JOIN acquisitions ON companies.id = acquisitions.company_id
WHERE companies.created_at >= acquisitions.delivery_date
```

The `companies.created_at` is a date column and `acquisitions.delivery_date` is a dateTime one.

If I do this one record is skipped

```
companies.created_at = '2021-04-16'
acquisitions.delivery_date = '2021-04-16 10:00:00'
```

We see that `delivery_date` is not greater that `created_at` BUT both are on the same day. So how can I parse to date and then compare, I've tried with `date(acquisitions.delivery_date)` and `cast(acquisitions.delivery_date as DATE)` and didn't work

Comment: **WHERE companies.created_at >= DATE(acquisitions.delivery_date)** must work. see **SELECT '2021-04-16' >= date('2021-04-16 10:00:00')**

Answer (score 0):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jB1PyysytiusorEJoHuwx8/0

```
SELECT *
  FROM companies
  INNER JOIN acquisitions
    ON companies.id= acquisitions.company_id
 WHERE companies.created_at >= date(acquisitions.delivery_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM companies
  INNER JOIN acquisitions
    ON companies.id= acquisitions.company_id
 WHERE companies.created_at + INTERVAL 1 DAY > acquisitions.delivery_date
```

I'd prefer this variant because the amount of rows in `companies` must be less than one in `acquisitions`. So the query will be slightly faster than with `WHERE companies.created_at >= DATE(acquisitions.delivery_date)`.